# CreateFileMapping ends with "Not enough disk space" error

Tags: c, windows, api, mapping

I have a problem understanding how to use the API function `CreateFileMapping(...)`.

I've been trying to map a small file and then reverse it's content. It has only about 1 Kb, but I keep getting the "Not enough memory" error.

I have opened the file by calling `CreateFile` and got it's size with `GetFileSize`.

Then I call:

```
CreateFileMapping(fileHandle, 
                  NULL, 
                  PAGE_READWRITE | SEC_RESERVE, 
                  fileSize + 1, 
                  fileSize + 1, 
                  NULL);
```

I suspect that the problem is with passing the `fileSize + 1` as `dwFileOffsetHigh`and `dwFileOffsetLow`, but I have a hard time understanding what should I pass to it instead.

Any hints are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dwFileOffsetHigh` and `dwFileOffsetLow` are two 32 bit values that are combined to form a single 64 bit value. This function was implemented this way because it pre-dates widespread compiler support for 64 bit values.

I think your misunderstanding is in believing that the high and low mean upper and lower limits.

In your case your value (assuming `fileSize` is around 1KB) is nowhere near requiring 64 bits so you should pass `fileSize+1` for `dwFileOffsetLow` and `0` for `dwFileOffsetHigh`.

However, if you are attempting to map the entire file you can simply pass `0` for both parameters.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366537%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> **dwMaximumSizeHigh** [in]
>
> The high-order DWORD of the maximum size of the
>   file mapping object.
>
> **dwMaximumSizeLow** [in]
>
> The low-order DWORD of the maximum size of the
>   file mapping object.
>
> If this parameter and dwMaximumSizeHigh are 0 (zero), the maximum size
>   of the file mapping object is equal to the current size of the file
>   that hFile identifies.
>
> An attempt to map a file with a length of 0 (zero) fails with an error
>   code of ERROR_FILE_INVALID. Applications should test for files with a
>   length of 0 (zero) and reject those files.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that it was something along those lines. I read it, but somehow couldn't understand it. Thanks for making it clear for me!

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to create a very big file mapping. `dwFileOffsetHight` and `dwFileOffsetLow` are the high and low 32 bit components of a 64bit integral. Use `GetFileSizeEx` instead to get both components of the file size.