# dwFileOffsetHigh and dwFileOffsetLow explained

Tags: c++, 64-bit

I am trying to write a file to disk but it is crashing when I attempt to write a file larger then 4 gigabytes. I am currently using the call:

```
fileMap= CreateFileMapping( fileHandle, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, (DWORD)size, NULL );
```

I believe that this is the problem. Reading the documentation it says that I can save files of 64 bit size with this call using the dwMaximumSizeHigh and dwMaximumSizeLow. I am a bit confused as how these work?

This [CreateFileMapping ends with "Not enough disk space" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7799914/createfilemapping-ends-with-not-enough-disk-space-error/7799967#7799967) explains that "dwFileOffsetHigh and dwFileOffsetLow are two 32 bit values that are combined to form a single 64 bit value. "

So how do I pass a value into this function that will create a big enough file map for a 64 bit file? I tried passing in two (DWORD)size for min and max but it still crashes. How would I go about creating a file bigger then 32 bit size with this function?

Comment: This is not a duplicate! I found that post and am unsure of how to use that to pass into this function. Please do not close.

Comment: You asked, "So how do I form one 64 bit value?" It's right there in plain text in your final paragraph. Did you mean to ask something else?

Comment: What values did you try passing? Is it possible that the error is accurate for the size you provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest and clearest way to extract 32-bit parts from a 64-bit integer may be with the use of [`LARGE_INTEGER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383713.aspx) or [`ULARGE_INTEGER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383742.aspx) as shown on [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0a88eb46-ce2c-4e65-85b6-16bc59b8f21f/how-to-convert-64bit-value-to-2-long-values):

```
ULARGE_INTEGER maxSize;
maxSize.QuadPart = size; /* your 64-bit value here */
fileMap = CreateFileMapping(fileHandle, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE,
                            maxSize.HighPart, maxSize.LowPart, NULL);
```

Comment: I think you mean [`ULARGE_INTEGER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383742.aspx). I also don't understand why you didn't like to the actual MSDN docs.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I thought the usage examples would be more likely to help than the easily findable union documentation. But your point about the unsigned HighPart was well worth fixing.

Comment: This worked fantastic thank you! Though the ULARGE_INTEGER gives a highpart which is a DWORD and the LARGE_INTEGER gives a Long which fits into the method better.

Comment: @marsh You're welcome. But I don't understand why a `LONG` would be better, given that [`CreateFileMapping`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537.aspx) takes two `DWORD` values for maximum size.

Comment: Yes you are quite right, sorry I was looking at another function I was using later.

Answer (score 2):

Extract the low and high parts like this:

```
uint64_t size = ...;
uint32_t sizeLow = size & 0xffffffff;
uint32_t sizeHigh = size >> 32;
```